# Erro ao verificar Assinatura Digital - "unable to load Private Key"

Tags: hash, openssl, assinatura-digital, prompt

**Para criação de uma Assinatura Digital é necessário:**
  - Chave Privada.
  - Chave Pública.
  - HASH do arquivo que será Assinado.

**Estou utilizando o seguinte algoritmo para o processo:**

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
Fonte: http://maxicertificadodigital.com.br/sobre.php

---

Seguindo esses passos, estou ultilizando o OpenSSL para gerar esses arquivos, só que estou com alguns problemas...

**Gerando a Chave Privada:**

```
openssl genrsa -out chave_privada.pem 1024
```

chave_privada.pem:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXQIBAAKBgQDSH6KlEmqxj9Y68d+qRGtlfDrrhLMT+D0tVa6gWtcH58UqyPAW
qOQOshUnBqojiuyVxpGc/fSUgAnZTSf0pdtTDzRv84AETYEZZe5RvP/vN9HqQZG7
RoNAwjWZiilvQFMDiHn9SB4EvxfcbRvCqpJklyuTigFDOP7Bgl4Jha+UWwIDAQAB
AoGBAJfVzlSUC08FjhuH/kRuLmDmNTlM6Y5rmeFxgb9UBQAsZZg2HO9y2WEZJBnQ
Qg9u6uiL1VrpU9we7X79tvqdAu8hs5C7XNS8bt861AaeBcu1V24vHcj8uIpz5j6d
V+30s8PmtY/JQfnn5pSk8h1KHi7pJp7bYfv0q5qBZ4p2+CShAkEA79dGC/zN/QyL
+Kuc1aCszXTix/Y8exz3hCK2WHR2g5lzOClXJWFM0a4FT/PYXI/z7+KBqcKHOXu/
CmwsWC+gUQJBAOBHzaDtOUfV0eRoQ20TXTuPRzd2fKrWf2fbP62MtqHe4FfgC2hv
TUcvHr996JsnA+NUYOyXt3AAmbXjlSugSusCQQDKPe4cJ6YPTugs3ZFXdrCgY4Lj
+RhQ/EEfVCIM/s/88oV9AycwJxce7K4gGFAG5YBedNK/soBSka2rfUH7btWxAkAW
ZDTMX0K7wEYvRpWMu0UwoBJdIDA8IiQgK0yFOCo3qPe+7jhVWd9ePv8T4S8q5k9G
D/OJS3Bd90FhXnJTI7K3AkAtYaoDxVTC8atbAWJZE+2tdqbepCopzpwAThro5Ff0
Ping/e9cCEt+zzNm+yPNQFXf48Xks9WQmZmk2qVzggUL
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Gerando a Chave Pública apartir da Chave Privada:**

```
openssl rsa -in chave_privada.pem -pubout -out chave_publica.pem
```

chave_publica.pem:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDSH6KlEmqxj9Y68d+qRGtlfDrr
hLMT+D0tVa6gWtcH58UqyPAWqOQOshUnBqojiuyVxpGc/fSUgAnZTSf0pdtTDzRv
84AETYEZZe5RvP/vN9HqQZG7RoNAwjWZiilvQFMDiHn9SB4EvxfcbRvCqpJklyuT
igFDOP7Bgl4Jha+UWwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**Gerando o HASH do arquivo:**

```
openssl dgst -sha256 texto.txt > hash
```

hash:

```
SHA256(texto.txt)= f32c22e9ca0fca1049df4467c1ce794229fb760f732cb05054c7a14a00a22a28
```

**Gerando a Assinatura:**

```
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey chave_privada.pem -keyform PEM -in hash > signature
```

**Verificando se assinatura confere com o arquivo:**

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey chave_publica.pem -keyform PEM -in signature
```

E retorna o seguinte erro no Prompt:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
unable to load Private Key
1300:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib
.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Alguem pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você especifica a opção `inkey`, o padrão é tratá-la como uma chave privada. Se você quer verificar a assinatura usando uma chave pública, é necessário usar também a opção `-pubin`:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey chave_publica.pem -pubin -keyform PEM -in signature
```

[Documentação do rsautl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html).